# Dragging between two calendars along with revert() in angular FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have two calendars (source and destination), I want to drag an event from **source** to **destination**.

In the destination calendar, there is an event named `eventReceive`;
In this event sometime I need to call `revert()`. The problem is that `info.revert();` works in the destination calendar, but I need to also restore the event to the source calendar as well. At the moment, it is removed and there is no obvious way to put it back.

Is it possible to do that?

**Source**

```
<full-calendar #sourceCalendar  
    ...
    (eventLeave)="eventLeave($event)">
</full-calendar>
```

**Destination**

```
<full-calendar #destinationCalendar
    ...
    (eventReceive)="eventReceive($event)">
</full-calendar>
```

In typescript:

```
eventReceive($event){
   // sometime I need to revert
   // How to revert ...
}
```

Comment: It's a function, so just call it. `eventReceive(info){ info.revert();
}`. It's not clear what the problem is? Maybe you didn't fully understand about passing references to functions around as parameters in JavaScript?

Comment: It's your right,  ``info.revert();``  works in one calendar, but my problem is: I want to revert an event from the destination calendar to the source  calendar(here I have two calendars)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You want it to be put back on the original calendar too. All I can suggest is to try handling [eventRemove](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRemove) on the source calendar, and saving the event object to another variable in your state. Then if you end up calling revert() in the destination calendar, you can also write code there to add the removed event back to the source calendar. I haven't tried it, but that sounds like it might be a workaround you can use.

Comment: P.S. you could maybe also add a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to the fullCalendar maintainers, to see if there's a way that revert() can have a flag to automatically restore the event onto the source calendar, if it knows the event was dragged from another calendar. I don't know if it's technically possible, but you can ask.

Comment: It's your right, I did, thanks for your contribution

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no built-in way to do this. All I can suggest is to try handling [eventRemove](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRemove) on the source calendar, and saving the event object to another variable in your state.

Then if you end up calling `revert()` in the destination calendar, you can also write code there to add the removed event back into the source calendar. I haven't tried it, but that sounds like it might be a workaround you can use.